# AngularJS directive: scope

Tags: angularjs, scope, directive

I have the example below:

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <p>Result is {{result}}!</p>
    <output-content data="name"></output-content>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'World';
    $scope.result = "no";

    $scope.changeLabel = function() {
        $scope.result = 'yes';
    }
});

app.directive('outputContent', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'outputContent.html',
        scope: {
            data: '=',
            result: '='
        },
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    };

});
```

outpuContent.html:

```
<div>
    {{data}}
    <button ng-click="changeLabel()">Change</button>
</div>
```

Plunker is: http://plnkr.co/edit/uzSrGcyQLeRNEIH7IXBf

I would like the result to be 'yes' when I click on the 'Change' button.

It doesn't work.

Could you please explain to me how to write the directive to do so ?

Regards.

Comment: I'm not sure about the complete directive but you output `{{data}}` in outputContent.html while the `changeLabel()` function updates `$scope.result`.

Comment: Yes I want to change the result. Data is not used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define variable in directive scope, but do not pass it. Just pass 
"result" into directive. E.g:

```
<output-content data="name" result="result"></output-content>
```

I forked your plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/12FXjUsVdPXhPIQ1mlHt?p=preview

Hope it helpful.

Comment: I was pleased to help you.

Answer (score 2):

In directive, delete scope . Now like This.. this will be work..

```
app.directive('outputContent', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'outputContent.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  };

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Scope is not needed. Kindly delete the scope.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.result = "no";

  $scope.changeLabel = function() {
    $scope.result = 'oh yeah';
  }
});

app.directive('outputContent', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'outputContent.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
  };

});
```

Comment: But I need the isolated scope for 'data'.